# How to show File quick action in the lightning page?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, quickaction

`File` Quick action is not showing on the lighting page but the in page layout `File` is added to Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions.

Please advise how to make "File" Quick action visible in the lighting page?

Comment: Quick action on which record page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible directly there is idea for this use case [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000COReQAO) . but there is work around by flow.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_files.htm

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cF6Yr5Y4Cv